# angular: after running "ng build --prod --aot=false";

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

The application is loading fine but resources which are inside asset folder gives 404 not found error, .css & .js files.

Comment: How are you referencing the asset folder? Did you possibly make relative paths like `../assets`?

Comment: @NeilLunn yes: skin_url: '../../assets/tinymce/skins/lightgray',
      language_url : '../../assets/tinymce/langs/ru.js',

Comment: Because you should be just doing `assets/` because the build is going to move those to the `dist` folder.

Comment: @NeilLunn You're right? but in dev mode it wouldn't work? I'm right???

Comment: Uses a virtual file system in dev mode. So the same root principles apply. You don't need to write relative paths.

Comment: @NeilLunn I would try, Thanks a lot

Comment: is assets folder there in dist ? check if its even included or not ?

Comment: @Rakeschand: Thanks for reply I already fix it through aid NeilLunn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses a virtual file system in `dev` mode. So the same root principles apply. You don't need to write relative paths.